# Git - reverting to previous commit but saving some latest commits

Tags: git, github

I have commits with following tags: 2.5.6, 2.5.5, 2.5.4, 2.5.3, 2.5.2, 2.5.1 and 2.5.0. I want to go back to the tag 2.5.0 but have also changes from commits 2.5.6 and 2.5.5 saved. So I want to get rid tags 2.5.4, 2.5.3, 2.5.2, 2.5.1. All of the commits after this should remain untouched in the tree. Can I do this like this?

```
git reset commit_id_for_tag_2.5.0;
```

and then what? how to include the tags 2.5.6 and 2.5.5? How to push the newly created commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags represent point-in-time snapshots of where the code was at that point. Even if you were to delete the tags, it wouldn't change the content of the subsequent commits that they pointed to.

If you wanted to get rid of the content, you can do:

```
git reset --hard 2.5.0
git cherry-pick 2.5.4..2.5.6
```

This will start you on a new branch from 2.5.0 and include any changes done since 2.5.4 (recall that 'changes in 2.5.5' is 'changes since 2.5.4') and if you want everything including 2.5.6 that you will have to ensure that commit is included as well.

You can then create a new tag and push that up; but given that you are effectively rebuilding a new history and throwing away the interim data, you should check that what you're doing makes sense.

You'll also need to push that change to the new branch that you tagged the 2.5.6 release from so that you continue to work on the new history and not the old history.

Comment: The .. syntax between any two tags shows the commits that are included between them. You can do `git log --oneline 2.5.4..2.5.6` to see what would be included with the cherry-pick operations.